# How to eliminate « a priori » all vectors in a list of vectors whose scalar product with a given vector is zero without calculating the product

Tags: linear-algebra, selection-problem

How to eliminate « a priori » all vectors in a list of vectors, whose scalar product with a given vector is zero, without actually calculating the product ?

One solution would be to store the components (as rows) in a relational database table and the to discard all vectors (with a SELECT statement) whose components are NULL in the columns where the components of the given vector are not NULL.

However that’s probably overkill.

I was thinking of associating with each array a second array of bits to  make a sort of mask, in order to be able to quickly compare the vector’s « masks » to implement a kind of pre-selection.

Is there a known straightforward solution to this problem?

Comment: Your idea will not eliminate all vectors that are perpendicular (scalar product is 0) to a given vector. It will work only if the target vector is parallel to the axis.

Comment: Wrong, if you associate :
a = {x, 0, 0} with  A = 0b100 
And 
 b = {0, y, 0}  with  B = 0b010 , for instance
then A & B will be 0

Comment: This is exactly what I said. It works only if its parallel to the axis. Take the example of $v_1=(0.5,0.5)$ and $v_2=(0.5,-0.5)$. They have 0 scalar product, but your idea wont work here

Comment: Erratum: In the example I had in mind, the components are limited to positive or null numbers.

Comment: In other words, what I aim at eliminating with this preselection is all the vectors whose scalar product will be null (respectively to a given vector) -prior to actually carrying out said scalar product-, in other words all the vector who share no components with a given vector (who belong to an orthogonal sub-space).